# What is the best way to create a collection of system properties for a google app engine website in python?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm trying to create some custom system properties, which can be changed in the admin section of the website.  While exploring some options I realized that I may be trying to do things too much like I would in C# and not embracing python patterns of programming.

I created an entity (SystemProperty) with a custom key and a single property (Value).  I then created a SystemProperties class with a bunch of "static properties" that represent the system properties stored in the datastore.  I want to use this SystemProperties class when ever I reference or update one of the system properties, however, I think I might be going about this the wrong way.  Anyone have a good suggestion for how to effectively manage system properties on Google App Engine using python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the type of properties. I use a module, appengine_config,py (hooks) and app.yaml (Environment Variables : os.environ) to store properties without using the datastore.
But this setup requires a new deployment of your application to update properties, or you have to build a module reload function.

See also Python Module configuration: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't work in my case because I need to allow others to change the system properties via the admin section of the website.

Comment: Here is an example config class from Nick Johnson. You can add a simple crud to change the config : http://blog.notdot.net/2011/10/Migrating-to-Python-2-7-part-1-Threadsafe

Answer (score 2):

We use [gae-init](http://gae-init.appspot.com/) to bootstrap all our projects. You can get a clear idea how we handle the system properties under the config section along with lots of other great automations for building deploying minifying etc..

Comment: Very impressive looking.  I'll have to investigate to see if this will suit our needs.

Comment: @threed You will need to spend some time with the implementation and some of the tutorials for the relevant technologies, but it will pays back in a not that long run. We use it for our minor weekend projects, but also for our commercial eye-tracking analysis platform. The author is always available if you find yourself in any need.

Comment: This is a great answer--really either solves my problem, but the other answer is a bit more minimal, so for posterity's sake...